# How can i add calendar which shows weekly as well as monthly calendar in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

How can I add a scrollable weekly calendar in Kotlin as shown in image? When I click on the icon in the top app bar, it should display the monthly calendar. As I scroll through the weekly calendar, it should scroll one week at a time, and when scrolling through the monthly calendar, it should scroll one month at a time and dates are infinite scroll.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIEwR.jpg)

Comment: Something like this? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/calendar-view-app-in-android-with-kotlin/

Comment: Yes but need weekly calendar as well as shown in image which is scrollable when i click on the button monthly calendar should show